# Connect Express js project to external MySQL databse via SSH

Tags: mysql, express, ssh, ini

I would like to know the best way to connect an Express.js project to an external MySql database using conf.ini ?

Should I use SSH ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for ssh, mysql has it's own protocol to connect remote servers, you only need to use [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) module for nodejs, the following code is to ensure connection between hosts:

```
const mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'remote_ip',
    user     : 'mysql_username',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'database_name'
});

connection.connect( function (err) {

    if (err) { 
        console.log('Cannot connect to mysql server', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected');
    }

    connection.end();

});
```

One last thing, make sure to edit mysql config file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and set `bind-address` parameter to `0.0.0.0`, and do not forget to restart mysql service: `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But what I have to do if I would like to use a conf.ini file for my project. With Nodemon, I have an "unsuccessful connection to database" error.

Comment: Which config.ini, are you using windows OS

Comment: Ok, I resolved my problem with this [link](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/275) . Thx for your help !